# How to suppress scientific notation in values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have `pandas.DataFrame` that contains some values with scientific notation and I want to change those values to a normal value without the `e+..`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [7.70000e+05, 4.5000000e+09, 3.219500e+05, 25000, 476577], 
    columns = ['Price'])
```

Comment: you could use pandas display.precision as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#frequently-used-options) (search for display.precision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
pd.set_option("float_format", lambda x: f"{x:.2f}")
df
          Price
0     770000.00
1 4500000000.00
2     321950.00
3      25000.00
4     476577.00
```